# Objective-C's "obj performSelector" vs objc_msgSend( )?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

Going through Apache Cordova's source code, I ran into two lines of code that I'm puzzled about:

```
    //[obj performSelector:normalSelector withObject:command];
    objc_msgSend(obj,normalSelector,command);
```

From Apple's documentation, there doesn't seem to be a lot of difference between these two methods.

**id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)** 
Sends a message with a simple return value to an instance of a class.

**- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelectorwithObject:(id)anObject**
Sends a message to the receiver with an object as the argument. (required)

What exactly is the difference between these two methods?  In the case above, both are sending messages with an object as an argument to a receiving object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're asking the difference between two "methods" but only one of them is actually a method.  The `objc_msgSend` function is, well, a function.  Not a method.

The `objc_msgSend` function is the function that you *actually* call when you invoke any method on any object in Objective C.  For example, the following two are basically equivalent:

```
// This is what the compiler generates
objc_msgSend(obj, @selector(sel:), param);

// This is what you write
[obj sel:param];

// You can check the assembly output, they are *almost* identical!
```

The major difference here is that `objc_msgSend` does not get type checked by the compiler -- or at least, its arguments don't get type checked against the selector's parameter types. So the following are roughly equivalent:

```
[obj performSelector:normalSelector withObject:command];
objc_msgSend(obj, @selector(performSelector:withObject:),
             normalSelector, command);
```

But, that's a bit of a waste, since all `performSelector:withObject:` does is call `objc_msgSend`.

**HOWEVER:** You should stay away from `obc_msgSend` because it is not type-safe, as mentioned above.  All the apache devs are doing is removing a single method call, which will only give you very *slight* performance benefits in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

The commented out line is correct, the `objc_msgSend()` line is incorrect in that it needs to be explicitly typed (varargs are not compatible with non-varargs function calls on some platforms sometimes).

Effectively they do the same thing.  Really, the method call version is just a wrapper around `objc_msgSend()`.